# Reserving an IP address on a Huawei B310 router

Tags: router

I cant find any option for this on the router pages.
Trying to tie down a Camera to a fixed internal ip.
I dont possess a computer..am using Android Pad to acccess router.
Can anyone help please..

Comment: Not sure about B310 router, but for HG659 you can go to the Home Network tab, and from there to LAN interface on the left-hand side, and then click on DHCP reservation and create new static address.

Answer (score 2):

The B310 does not seem to offer DHCP reservation.

You can however define the range of the DHCP server and manually set your camera to an IP address outside that range.

Or you could use another device as the DHCP server on your LAN, if you have one that supports reservations (and disable the DHCP server on the B310).

Comment: Thanks very much..you've given me ideas..but not sure how to manually assign an ip..if router resets or camera gets removed for some reason won't the DHCP put it back where it wants to again?

Comment: The DHCP only gives addresses to devices that ask for them. If you configure your camera to use a fixed IP, then it won't ask and it will always use that adress (which can become a problem the day you decide to change your network adressing).